# Run command when bash closes because of timeout

Tags: bash, rhel

I am aware of the solution to use

```
trap your_command EXIT
```

but what I want is to run the command ONLY when bash terminates because of a timeout by setting the TMOUT variable.  Is there any way out?

My environment: RedHat 7.7

Answer (score 1):

The only option I see is to put that command in your `~/.bash_logout` file; that file is executed if the current shell is a login shell and the current shell is not a subshell.

In the [source code for bash where a command is read for evaluation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/eval.c#n311), it sets an alarm handler for the value of `TMOUT`:

```c
  if (interactive)
    {
      tmout_var = find_variable ("TMOUT");

      if (tmout_var && var_isset (tmout_var))
      {
        tmout_len = atoi (value_cell (tmout_var));
        if (tmout_len > 0)
        {
          old_alrm = set_signal_handler (SIGALRM, alrm_catcher);
          alarm (tmout_len);
        }
      }
    }
```

That [alarm handler](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/eval.c#n241) looks like this:

```
static sighandler
alrm_catcher(i)
     int i;
{
  printf (_("\007timed out waiting for input: auto-logout\n"));
  fflush (stdout);
  bash_logout ();   /* run ~/.bash_logout if this is a login shell */
  jump_to_top_level (EXITPROG);
  SIGRETURN (0);
}
```

The [`bash_logout` function is defined as](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/exit.def#n158):

```
void
bash_logout ()
{
  /* Run our `~/.bash_logout' file if it exists, and this is a login shell. */
  if (login_shell && sourced_logout++ == 0 && subshell_environment == 0)
    {
      maybe_execute_file ("~/.bash_logout", 1);
#ifdef SYS_BASH_LOGOUT
      maybe_execute_file (SYS_BASH_LOGOUT, 1);
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that and in both cases (timeout vs manual termination) the .bash_logout is executed.  Therefore unfortunately not a possible solution :(.

Comment: It's not a precise solution, granted. You could wrap the code inside `~/.bash_logout` with a test for `$TMOUT` being set to something above zero, but that's only an incremental improvement.

Comment: I did not fully understood the approach.  The $TMOUT does not decrements to 0 when the bash terminates because of a timeout.  What kind of test I could do in this case?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; it's a bad idea. If you always set TMOUT, then the test would always succeed, making it a worthless test.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the detailed inputs though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502915/differentiate-between-exit-and-session-timeout

Make use of shell env variable PROMPT_COMMAND and call a custom function.  In the custom function you can check if the Shell idle timeout and decide if the trap was called due to a timeout or shell exit.